# Turn it over/pick it up

Tags: word-usage

My Aunt ask my three year old cousin to pick up the trike that had turned over. So what should be used :

> - Pick it up .
> - Turn it over.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, you would need both.

First, you pick it up. After picking it up, you would be holding it in your hands, dangling in mid-air.

Then, you would turn it over so that it is right-side up.

Finally, you would set it back down on the ground again.

In colloquial English, however, you could say either *"pick it up"* or *"turn it over"*, and everyone would understand what you meant from context.

*"Pick it up"* is more idiomatic, implying that you would not only pick it up, but also turn it upright when doing so (since upright is its "natural" position from a human perspective).